# 日本語に違和感: ヘルプの「お礼とは?どうしたら開始できますか?」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

「お礼を開始する」という概念に違和感があります。「お礼を提示する」とかの方が良い気がします。
[image: 指摘用画像]

Comment: Bountyの和訳版が「[専門用語」のポスト](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/stack-overflow%e3%81%ae%e5%b0%82%e9%96%80%e7%94%a8%e8%aa%9e)に入っています。それを解決すれば、これも見直します。意見があれば専門用語にコメントや編集をすれば、助かります。

Comment: 承知しました。専門用語の方に提案します。

Comment: 2021年現在は、「懸賞とは？どうすれば懸賞金を提示できますか？」と改善されました。

Answer (score 3):

コメントにて supa さんがお教えくださったとおり、2021年現在は「懸賞とは？どうすれば懸賞金を提示できますか？」と改善されております。タグを[延期](/questions/tagged/%e5%bb%b6%e6%9c%9f)から[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)に変更いたしました  。

[image: 「懸賞とは？どうすれば懸賞金を提示できますか？」のスクリーンショット]