# ヘルプセンター: 「お礼とは？どうしたら開始できますか？」の改善

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

この投稿は 「[お礼とは？どうしたら開始できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) 」 の改善案です ([英語の原文はこちら](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty))。
コミュニティの総意を反映し「お礼」を「懸賞」に書き換えたいと思います！その他にも改善できる箇所があれば編集やコメントをお願いします。

---

### 懸賞とは？どうすれば懸賞金を提示できますか？

[良い質問を投稿し](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)、ステータスや進捗更新の[編集をして](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)、それでも [回答がつかない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) 場合は、懸賞金をかけて質問にもっと注意をひくことができます。

スタック・オーバーフローでの懸賞とは、回答に対して与えられる特別な信用度の授与です。提供するユーザーの個人的な信用度から拠出され、**払い戻しはできません**。満足のいく回答を得られなかった場合などに懸賞をかけることによって、より多くの注目と回答を集めることができるかもしれません。努力して獲得した自分の信用度を +50 点から +500 点までを使って、[*任意の*質問に懸賞として設定します](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties)。懸賞を提供するのに、質問の投稿者である必要はありません。

- **すべての懸賞金は前払いで、いかなる状況でも払い戻しできません。**
- 信用度の変化により [権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/privileges) の要件を満たさなくなった場合、そのような権限にアクセスできなくなります。
- 一度にかけられるアクティブな懸賞は 3 つまでです。
- 質問にかけられるアクティブな懸賞は 1 つだけです。
- 過度に宣伝目的な懸賞を避けるため、すでに回答を投稿した質問に懸賞を提供する場合は最低 100 点 (50 点ではなく) の信用度を費やさなければなりません。
- さらに、同じ質問に複数の懸賞を提供すると、後続の懸賞ごとに最低点が倍になっていきます (最初のお例は 50 点、2 番目は 100 点、3 番目は 200 点など)。
- 懸賞金は、いったん提示するとキャンセルできません。

#### 懸賞金を提示するとどうなりますか？

懸賞のついた質問には、すべての質問リストで特殊な指標が表示され、[トップページの [懸賞付き] タブ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) にも 7 日間表示されます。懸賞の対価には、通常の質問が受ける注目よりも多くの注目を自分の質問が受けられるようにすることがあります。ただし、懸賞は反応を*保証*するものではなく、懸賞の結果回答が得られなかった場合でも信用度の払い戻しはありません。

#### 懸賞金の提示方法は？いつ懸賞金を提示できますか？

懸賞金は、質問の投稿の 2 日後から提示できます。

懸賞金を提示するには、該当する質問の下にある "懸賞金を提示する" のリンクをクリックし、50 点から 500 点まで 50 点刻みの信用度を割り当てます。また、[懸賞の理由のリスト](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) から選択して、質問に対する現在の回答に満足していない理由を他のユーザーが分かるようにすることもできます。より詳細に何かを説明する必要がある場合は、懸賞の理由とともに表示されるオプションの追加カスタムテキストもあります。

#### 懸賞金はどのように授与されますか？

懸賞の期間は $BountyDurationInDays 日間継続します。懸賞は少なくとも 1 日の最低期間がなければなりません。懸賞が終了すると、手動で懸賞金を授与するための 24 時間の猶予期間があります。回答に懸賞金を授与するには、各回答の隣の懸賞金授与アイコンをクリックするだけです。(自分の回答に懸賞金を授与することはできません。)

$BountyDurationInDays 日 (プラス猶予期間) 以内に懸賞を授与しなかった場合、懸賞が開始された後で作成された回答のうち、最も得票が高かったもの (最低スコアは 2) に懸賞全額の半分が授与されます。同じスコアの該当する回答が 2 つ以上ある場合 (すなわちタイスコア)、もっとも古い回答に懸賞金が授与されます。これらの基準を満たす回答がない場合は、懸賞金は誰にも授与されません。

質問の所有者が懸賞金を提示した場合で、質問の所有者が懸賞期間中に投稿された回答を承認し、*かつ*懸賞金が明確に授与されない場合は、懸賞の所有者は承認したかが気に入ったものとみなして、懸賞の有効期限が切れた時点で懸賞の全額をその回答者に授与します。

特別ボーナスとして、懸賞金の授与によって獲得した信用度は、毎日の信用度の上限から除外されます。

---

関連：
[日本語に違和感：「お礼」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/163/14055)
[日本語に違和感: 「おすすめ」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2650/14055)
[日本語に違和感: ヘルプの「お礼とは?どうしたら開始できますか?」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/73/14055)